# Bootstrap + simple form checkbox grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a list of 20+ tags I want to present in a 4 column checkbox grid but I'm not quite sure what the cleanest way to do it is. I have the following form:

```
= simple_form_for(@fracture) do |f|
  = f.error_notification    
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :summary
    = f.input :tag_list, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.map(&:name), :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

The resulting form should be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/, but I'd like to have the logic confined in a `wrapper`or CSS rather than manually modifying the HTML.

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you get rid of the `<div class="controls span2">` column elements and add the `span2` class to the `label` elements, the `label` will have a set width and will float left. This will cause the check boxes to align to a grid.

```
<label class="checkbox span2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="option1"> Cash
</label>
```

You can force the grid to be four-columns by adding the `span10` class to the container element:

```
<div class="control-group span10">
```

*However*, this will cause the grid to flow left -> right and then create new rows instead of consecutive elements being stacked vertically. The only way I can think to have elements stacked vertically is to use the [multi-column layout functionality](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). I haven't used this before, and I don't actually know how well it works in the various browsers.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/57/) shows the two approaches, each with either a static width or a fluid width.

Comment: Thanks for your response - this is definitely the look I'm going for. However, I'm looking for a solution that uses simple_form wrappers rather than adding more HTML to the server side template.

Comment: No problem. By "using simple_form wrappers" do you mean to avoid adding the `span2` class to the `<label>` elements? If there is some specific HTML you want to stick to, can you post it? (Assuming the HTML in your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/) is to demo aesthetics.) Here is a more minimal setup: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/59/). It basically applies the settings from the `span2` to each of the `<label class="checkbox">` elements via the `float-checkboxes` class added to the `<form>`.

Comment: That's a very clean solution, but I'm looking for something that would take this haml `= f.input :tag_list, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.map(&:name), :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'` and, using some sort of a [Custom Wrapper](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers) add the appropriate markup/css classes that would render the checkboxes in a grid.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks for the explanation. I don't know ruby, so I'm probably barking up the wrong tree here... Assuming [`--boostrap` config](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb#L12), according to [this line](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb#L55) in the example, could you replace `:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'` with `:item_wrapper_class => 'span2'`? That would, theoretically, yield something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/60/). Lol, anyway, just curious. :)